# I've been tasked to put this formula to sum 48. Logically it does sum up but I don't know why it rationally sums up 47

Tags: bluej

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q7vni.png)

Since the variables are a=11, b=3, c=19; I wrote a formula that would sum to 48 like (c++ + a--) + (c++ - b--) when looked logically, (20 + 10) + (20 - 2) which should sum up to 48, but the output is 47.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly note the difference between pre-increment(or decrement) and post-increment(or decrement)

***PRE-INCREMENT MEANS  CHANGE  THEN USE***
***For example if it is `++x` it is pre increment*** in this case the value of x will become 2 if it was 1 initially

***Post-Increment Means use then change***
***For example if it is `x++` it is pre increment*** in this case the value of x will be 1  itself if it was 1 initially and will make it 2 when the variable `x` is encountered the next time

So in this case only post increment is used
so it will be  (19 + 11) + (20 - 3) so it will add up to 47

Check out the image description for more clearness in concept

[IMAGE FOR UNDERSTANDING](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9DMJL.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention to the difference `x++` and `++x` and `x=x+1`, simply you can regard `x++` as the following 2 steps:

1. return x for computing
2. x=x+1

and the `++x` means:

1. x=x+1
2. return x for computing

So, the code you write actually compute (19 + 11) + (20 - 3) = 47, and finally a=10, b=2, c=21.